# Config file management

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, drone.io

When using build system like Drone.io, or Jenkins, what is the best way to manage configuration files? In Jenkins I use a plugin that let me create some config text files. However, there is no grouping. I wish to know how you guys are managing your config files for different environments like test, stage, prod.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) See [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin):

> Adds the ability to provide configuration files (i.e., settings.xml
>   for maven, XML, groovy, custom files, etc.) loaded through the Jenkins
>   UI which will be copied to the job's workspace.

2) See [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin):

> the configuration slicing plugin can handle properties on any
>   collection, such as slaves, or builds of a project.

Comment: Thanks Gerold. Do you know how I can have the same capability in Drone.io?

Comment: @Khanetor You're welcome. I don't know. I'm not familiar with Drone. Ask [Brad at Drone](http://blog.drone.io/) directly.